# resizing elements with display table

Tags: html, css

On the following [website][1] I have a banner section which I have told to display as display table with table cells. I used this because I needed to align the image to the middle of the banner.

HTML:

```
<div class="banner banner-large">
    <div class="banner-inner">
        <div class="banner-col col-page-intro">
            <h1>Collect. <br>Transport. <br>Recycle.</h1>       
        </div>
        <div class="banner-col col-banner-image">
                <img src="/files/1813/9705/0946/gd-hero.png" alt="">
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
 .banner {
        background:$red;
        color:$white;
        position:relative;
        overflow: hidden;
}

    .banner-inner {
        display:table;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;

        @include bp(XS) {
            display:block;
        }
    }
    .banner-col {
        display:table-cell;

        width:50%;

        @include bp(XS) {
            display:block;
            width:100%;
        }
    }

    .col-page-intro {
        padding:40px 0 40px 60px;
        vertical-align: top;

        @include bp(L) {
            padding:20px 0 20px 30px;
        }
        @include bp(XS) {
            width:100%;
            padding:20px 15px;
        }
    }

    .col-banner-image {
        text-align:center;
        padding: 0 30px;
        vertical-align: middle;

        @include bp(XS) {
            text-align:left;
            margin-bottom:20px;
            padding:0 10px;
        }
    }
```

If you [compare the website][2] in both chrome and firefox you'll notice chrome honours the width and resizing of the image (max-width 100%) whereas firefox does not.

What can I do to make both browsers behave as Chrome is currently?

edit: this only works in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `width: 100%;` and probably `display: block;` to your `img`:

```
.col-banner-image img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Tried that, trouble is the image gets massive on large screens as there is no max-width on the container. If I float the col-banners the image resizes but stays at the top of the div which is standard.

Comment: Got it, at large widths I'll use a media query to swap `width 100%` to `width auto`.